# Yocto Qt5 Image

Tags: qt, qt5, yocto

I am using Freescale i.MX6DL Core and wanted to build Qt5.5 (master branch of Jethro with it).

I have successed with the Tutorial from Wandboard but the qmake is Daisy branch 5.2.1
[Qt5 Wandboard Installation](http://wiki.wandboard.org/index.php/Building_Qt5_using_yocto_on_Wandboard)

When I change to master or Jethro, the following error shows up and I have no idea how to fix it.

> ERROR: ExpansionError during parsing /mountdata/hio-yocto-bsp/sources/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtmultimedia_git.bb: Failure expanding variable qmake5_base_do_configure: ExpansionError: Failure expanding variable EXTRA_QMAKEVARS_PRE, expression was  ${@bb.utils.contains('PACKAGECONFIG', 'alsa', '', 'CONFIG+=done_config_alsa', d)} ${@bb.utils.contains('PACKAGECONFIG', 'pulseaudio', '', 'CONFIG+=done_config_pulseaudio', d)} ${@bb.utils.contains('PACKAGECONFIG', 'openal', '', 'CONFIG+=done_config_openal', d)} ${@bb.utils.contains('PACKAGECONFIG', 'gstreamer', 'GST_VERSION=1.0', '', d)} ${@bb.utils.contains('PACKAGECONFIG', 'gstreamer010', 'GST_VERSION=0.10', '', d)} ${@bb.utils.contains_any('PACKAGECONFIG', 'gstreamer gstreamer010', '', 'CONFIG+=done_config_gstreamer', d)} which triggered exception AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'contains_any'

Then I follow another tutorial using Yocto 2.0 and install Jethro
[Building Wandboard Systems with Yocto](http://www.jumpnowtek.com/wandboard/Wandboard-Systems-with-Yocto.html).  It showed me a bunch of problems because of no .bb recipe available.  For example, meta-oe opencv*.bbappend are the only files in the directory.  But that's come with git clone, and I did not need the .bb recipe before for this.

Please help, Thank you.